# Sqlfluff for User-Defined Functions

Tags: sql, user-defined-functions, sqlfluff

I'm trying to use sqlfluff on a sql script that creates a user-defined function, but the linter fails to parse the script no matter how I modify the code. I have looked through the sqlfluff documentation as well as searched online for any indication if sqlfluff can be used for user-defined functions and have not found any indication either way.

Does anyone know if I should not be using sqlfluff for a user-defined function or if there is documentation regarding sqlfluff for this purpose that I have not found?

I have attempted to modify the code in various ways to get the linter to parse the script properly. Additionally, I have looked for documentation on this issue from the sqlfluff website directly as well as searching online generally.

Comment: What SQL dialect are you using?

Comment: in my .sqlfluff file I have: dialect = tsql